# Unable to turn off wifi in Android

Tags: java, android, automation, android-espresso, wifimanager

I'm working on core automation using espresso in android. I have to test some offline feature in app, for that i need to make internet connection off. I'm using `wifiManager` but not working.

I'm using following code snippet

```
Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

Also added below permission `AndroidTest/AndroidMenifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

**Exception:**

> java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10103 nor
>   current process has android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE. at
>   android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1942) at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910) at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860) at
>   android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.setWifiEnabled(IWifiManager.java:1323)
>   at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.setWifiEnabled(WifiManager.java:1804)

Also tried to allow permission before turning wifi off using adb but no success at all

```
getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
            "pm grant " + getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                    + " android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE");
getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
            "pm grant " + getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getPackageName()
                    + " android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE");
```

Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you add a `GrantPermissionRule`. Something like `@get:Rule val grantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE)` (this is kotlin, so I'll let you translate it to java if that's what you need).

Comment: Thank @Michael but this is also not working in my case.